# Copy directory into Dropbox with Dropbox.js API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to copy a directory from my local machine to a Dropbox account using the [dropbox.js API](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropbox.js/0.10.3/dropbox.js). I can't find a way to do it. Anyone have any ideas on how to do this? I'm running it as a Node.js script, not on a web server.

[Here is the Dropbox.js Github page.](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what issue did you run into? `writeFile` is the method in the JS SDK to upload a file.

Comment: @smarx I tried using `writeFile`, but it seems as though that doesn't accept directories. Then I tried the `copy` method, but it seems as though that doesn't accept directories either.

Comment: You'll have to loop over all the files you want to upload and call `writeFile` for each. There's no SDK method to do that automatically.

Comment: Okay. Just to make sure, using [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback) would be the best way to do this, right?